555 timer automatic triggering in monostable mode
I have a 555 timer in monostable mode connected to a momentary push button. My goal is to power the circuit, and then press a button that will start the 555 timer for 10 seconds, then completely stop, until the button is pressed again. I’ve tried making a prototype on Tinkercad, and it works well. However, the LED always turns on for 10 seconds without pressing the button.
How can I make it only start when I press the push button, not on power-up?

Here's the schematic:


There is no question you want to have answered. Please ask a question by editing it in.

Hi, @Justme Is it clear now?

Solved: Just connect the C1+ to BAT1+ and C1- to THR and DIS

Thanks for the update. Now you can mark it as solved.

Does it solve the problem in Tinkercad or in real life?

@Justme In tinkercad. I haven't tried IRL yet.

@Michael Please understand that even if it works in Tinkercad now, not even the datasheet can tell you how it works in such a scenario, so Tinkercad may simulate it incorrectly. Perhaps you should use the RESET pin for proper operation.
